# How to Textarea Working like Wordpress post Textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, textarea

I know this is very funny question but I am asking,

I am trying to build my own blogging admin panel and I was create `<textarea>` but when I copy & past something into it, then it not come with full style. But I see into wordpress that working very nicely.

So please tell me or give me solution.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress uses it's own WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor or a Rich Text Editor. Unfortunately a `<textarea>` tag by itself will not facilitate the additional options and functionality that have been added to the element.

There are quite a few Javascript based plugins that you can use that can facilitate some of the functionality from Wordpress. The most commonly used one that I've seen (that is also freely available) is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), however there are plenty out there both paid and [unpaid](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/).

Comment: plz vote me also, I am in negative

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to @redreddington's answer.

I've often used the following WYSIWYG texteditors:

- [Redactor (paid)](https://imperavi.com/redactor/)
- [TinyMCE (free,
  with paid options)](https://www.tinymce.com/)
- [Quill (free)](http://quilljs.com/)

They all have benefits and disadvantages, but I often go with Redactor.

Comment: "often go with Redactor" !!! - clearly I need a raise.

Comment: @redreddington haha, what do you mean?

Comment: $145 is a tad steep for me :P

Comment: haha I totally get what you mean! It helps when the client is sporting the bill :P